# I need to decipher my Huawei hg8245h modem sip phone password

Tags: decryption, router

I have a Huawei hg8245h modem and unfortunately, I have forgotten my sip phone password and my ISP does not provide it to me. I have downloaded the modem configuration and this is the section related to the SIP password:

```
<SIP AuthUserName="XXXX" AuthPassword="XXXX" URI="">
<X_HW_Digitmap DMName="" DigitMap="" DigitMapStartTimer="20" DigitMapShortTimer="5" DigitMapLongTimer="10"/>
</SIP>
```

I have tried to use this tool to decipher with no success:
https://andreluis034.github.io/huawei-utility-page/#cipher

Can someone decipher this password for me or give me help to dicpher it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tool mentioned here: https://github.com/hu60t/hu60wap6/files/6206916/Huawei.configuration.encryption.and.decryption.tools.zip

Reference: https://gist.github.com/staaldraad/605a5e40abaaa5915bc7

Comment: Hello and welcome to re.se! In the current state - your answer is a link only answer. If the link goes down - this answer wouldn't be relevant. I'd recommend adding a summary of the solution you mention in the link.